# Global variables changed only in some cases

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, global-variables

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    #create variable to store final sorted list
    sortedLst = []
    #add any number into the list so the program can start inserting
    sortedLst.append(lst.pop())

    #for each item left over in the original list compare to sorted list
    for sortInd in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
    #for each index to sort
        for sortingInd in range(len(sortedLst),-1,-1):
            if sortingInd == 0 or sortingInd == len(sortedLst):
                sortedLst.insert(sortingInd,lst.pop())
                break
            if lst[sortInd] > sortedLst[sortingInd]:
                sortedLst.insert(sortingInd,lst.pop())
                break

    print(sortedLst) #gives [1,2,3]
    print(lst) #gives []
    lst = sortedLst
    print(lst) #gives [1,2,3]

lst = [3,2,1]
insertionSort(lst)
#lst should be [1,2,3] yet gives []
print(lst)
```

I am trying to program an insertion sort, the insertion sort itself does work however as this is part of more sorts I have programmed, I specifically do not want to declare a new variable for the sorted list outside the function and have the function return a sorted list to be consistent with my other functions. eg i don't want:

```
lst = [3,2,1]
newLst = insertionSort(lst)
```

Instead I want the insertionSort function to change my original lst variable and it does change when I pop the values to sort but does not change when I set it to the sortedLst before the function ends.

Thank you in advance for any answers :).

Comment: Python has excellent documentation, this should be explained in the section on the [execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html). For example that `lst` inside your function **isn't** the `lst` outside your function and that `lst = x` doesn't copy `x`.

Comment: Hm, I understand that and it makes some sense as to why my lst doesn't change to my sortedLst when I do 'lst = sortedLst' but why does lst.pop() actually pop from my lst outside the function and not just the one inside?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know about the difference between names, references (pointers) and values?

Comment: I am pretty sure I do, references refer to memory locations, values being the thing stored at the memory location, names being the name of the reference to a memory location. Correct me if I'm wrong.
My question has been answered now in the comments of the answer by Daniel Roseman. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change any global variables here at all.

You could fix this by declaring `lst` as global within your `insertionSort` function, but I'm not sure why you want to; it would be much better to simply return `sortedLst` and print that.

Comment: Is my original 'lst = [3,2,1]' not classed as a global variable since its declared in the outermost scope.
Also, I know I can return my sortedLst but I am wondering why my original lst is changed from [3,2,1] to [] but then not from [] to my sortedLst.
Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: No, because that global variable is shadowed by the `lst` parameter in the function itself. It so happens that they originally point to the same list, which is why your `pop` works; but then you break that by reassigning the local name `lst` to point  to `sortedLst`. If you wanted to keep the reference, you could do `lst[:] = sortedLst`.

Comment: I understand now. I know there are better ways of going about this problem, however I was just wanting to understand why this was happening. Thank you :)